# Could the person who taped Donald Sterling go to prison?

Tags: us-state-laws

Today I read Kareem [Abdul-Jabbar's excellent Time op-ed](http://time.com/79590/donald-sterling-kareem-abdul-jabbar-racism/) on the Donald Sterling allegations. In it, Kareem expresses his hopes that the person who taped Sterling will go to prison.

Is this a real possibility? What are the legal ramifications of audio recording someone without his or her expressed consent in California?

Comment: It is my understanding that Sterling requested that their conversations were recorded (since he had a habit of forgettng what they discussed earlier in the day). I believe that CA is a state that requires all parties to be informed that they are being recorded. I believe it is a felony, but will require some time to look up the statute.

Comment: @user1873 "It is my understanding that Sterling requested that their conversations were recorded (since he had a habit of forgettng what they discussed earlier in the day)."  Do you have a source for that?  That would be really interesting if true.

Comment: While  love the exposure that the question gives to a very thoughtful piece of writing; isn't this more of a legal question than political?

Comment: @DVK: There's no official site [for legal questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-law-questions-if-not-why-not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, yes. California is known as a "two party consent" state, meaning both parties to any conversation must consent to its recording. California's two-party consent law ([Section 632(a)](http://law.onecle.com/california/penal/632.html) of the California Penal Code) is a misdemeanor and carries with it a fine of up to $2500 and imprisonment of up to one year. The statute also includes a civil penalty.

> 1. (a) Every person who, intentionally and without the consent of all parties to a confidential communication, by means of any electronic amplifying or recording device, eavesdrops upon or records the confidential communication, whether the communication is carried on among the parties in the presence of one another or by means of a telegraph, telephone, or other device, except a radio, shall be punished by a fine not exceeding two thousand five hundred dollars ($2,500), or imprisonment in the county jail not exceeding one year, or in the state prison, or by both that fine and imprisonment. If the person has previously been convicted of a violation of this section or Section 631, 632.5, 632.6, 632.7, or 636, the person shall be punished by a fine not exceeding ten thousand dollars ($10,000), by imprisonment in the county jail not exceeding one year, or in the state prison, or by both that fine and imprisonment.

If Sterling consented to the recording the statute would not apply.

Comment: Welcome to Politics.SE. this answer would be improved by linking to the source. I will edit it to show what i mean.

Comment: This might be incorrect. I saw a news clip suggesting that Sterling requested she tape him because he forgets what he says. If this is true, the standard of two-party consent may have been met.

Comment: Thank you 1873, I'll be sure to link and block quote in the future. Avi, you are absolutely correct, which is why I noted at the end that the statute would not apply if Sterling consented to the recording.

Answer (score 0):

Could? Probably?
Would? Unlikely?
Sued and tied in knots by Sterling's lawyers? Absolutely.
Some years back (1997) a case in Florida had interesting similarities; an elderly couple traveling to Florida happened to pick up a conference call on their police scanner. They electronically happened on cell phone conversation of Newt Gingrich and several high ranking Republicans. Recognizing the  call may have some historical importance, the couple taped the conversation. 
http://www.nytimes.com/1997/04/24/us/florida-couple-are-charged-in-taping-of-gingrich-call.html
Tape was made public and couple was charged by U.S. Justice Department. The charge was intercepting the call (which was traveling through public airways) of a mobile phone.

Comment: It's very encouraging to see that the Justice Department has been completely corrupt and subverted to meet the needs of political establishment for decades.